# Residual analysis of the following recurrence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, recurrence-relations, monotone-functions

I'm trying to perform an analysis of a recursion. I'll provide a bit of background and then the actual question later.

Let $\left\{ \omega_j \right\}_{j\in\mathbb{N}} = \left\{ \arctan \left(2^{-j}\right) \right\}_{j\in\mathbb{N}}$, let $\theta \in \left[-\sum_{j=0}^{+\infty} \omega_j, \sum_{j=0}^{+\infty} \omega_j\right]$ given, we can prove that the following recursion

$$
t_j = \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
0 & j = 0 \\
t_{j-1} + d_{j-1}\omega_{j-1} & j > 0
\end{array}
\right.
$$
with
$$
d_j = \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
1 & t_j \leq \theta \\
-1 & t_j > \theta
\end{array}
\right.
$$
converges to $\theta$. For given angle $\psi$ the rotation matrix (counter clockwise is given by)

$$
R_{\psi} = \begin{pmatrix}
\cos(\psi) & -\sin(\psi) \\
\sin(\psi) & \cos(\psi)
\end{pmatrix} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + \tan^2(\psi)}} \begin{pmatrix}
1 & -\tan(\psi) \\
\tan(\psi) & 1
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Using the defintion of $t_j$ above we can write the following transformation
$$
\vec{x}_{j+1} = R_{t_{j+1}}\vec{x}_0 = R_{t_j + d_j\omega_j} \vec{x}_0 = R_{d_j \omega_j} R_{t_j}  \vec{x}_0 = R_{d_j \omega_j} \vec{x}_{j} \Rightarrow x_{j+1} = R_{d_j\omega_j} \vec{x}_j.
$$
Given the definition of $\omega_j$ we can write
$$
R_{d_j\omega_j} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+2^{-2j}}}\left(I + d_j2^{-j}J \right) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+2^{-2j}}}A_j,
$$
where
$$
\begin{array}{l}
I = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix} \\
J = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & -1 \\
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\end{array}.
$$
Now the question...Suppose that $\vec{x}_0 = \left(\frac{1}{K},0\right)^T$ with
$$
K = \prod_{j=0}^{+\infty}(1+2^{-2j}),
$$
The recursion I want to study is this one
$$
\vec{x}_{j+1} = A_j \vec{x_j},
$$
(without the scale factor)
specifically I want to study the properties of the residual
$$
\lVert \vec{x} - \vec{x}_j \rVert = \lVert \vec{\epsilon}_j \rVert,
$$
and I managed to derive the relation
$$
\vec{\epsilon}_{j+1} = A_j \vec{\epsilon}_j - d_jJ \vec{x}.
$$
Here $x$ is the limit value (which happens to be $(\cos(\theta),\sin(\theta))^T$.

I was specifically wondering whether or not the sequence of the error is monotonically decreasing, namely is $\lVert \vec{\epsilon}_{j+1} \rVert < \lVert \vec{\epsilon}_{j} \rVert$. My attempt was based on observing that the induced matrix is

$$
\begin{array}{l}
\lVert A_j \rVert_2 = \sqrt{1+2^{-j}} \\
\lVert d_j2^{-j} J \rVert_2 = 2^{-j} \lVert J \rVert_2 = 2^{-j}
\end{array},
$$
therefore using the triangular inequality I get
$$
\lVert \vec{\epsilon}_{j+1} \rVert_2 = \lVert A_j \vec{\epsilon}_j - d_j 2^{-j} J \vec{x} \rVert \leq \lVert A_j \vec{\epsilon}_j \rVert_2 + \lVert d_jJ \vec{x} \rVert_2 \leq \lVert A_j \rVert_2 \lVert \vec{\epsilon}_j \rVert_2 + \lVert d_j 2^{-j} J \rVert_2 \lVert \vec{x} \rVert_2 = \sqrt{1+2^{-j}} \lVert \vec{\epsilon}_j \rVert_2 + 2^{-j}
$$
namely I end up with the inequality

$$
\lVert \vec{\epsilon}_{j+1} \rVert_2 \leq \sqrt{1+2^{-j}} \lVert \vec{\epsilon}_j \rVert_2 + 2^{-j},
$$
but this doesn't seem enough to me to prove the monotonicity.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you sure about your definition of the rotation matrix ?

Comment: Now yes, sorry there was a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that we have a complicated description of the following simple geometric algorithm. Given a unit vector $\vec x$ with the direction (angle) $\theta$ and a vector $\vec x_0$ with the direction $0$ and carefully chosen length $l=1/K$, we build a sequence $\{\vec x_n\}$ approximating $\vec x$ as follows. At $j$-th step we stretch $\vec x_j$ by $\sqrt{1+2^{-2j}}$ and rotate it by $\omega_j$ towards $x$.

Then, a priori, an approximation error $e_j=\|\vec\epsilon_j\|$ can increase when a direction of $\vec x_j$ is already very close to the direction of $\vec x$, but we have to rotate it away. Lets check this. For each $j$ let $s_j=|t_j-\theta|$ be the angle between vectors $\vec x_j$ and $\vec x$ and $l_j$ be length of $\vec x_j$. Then $e_j^2=1+l_j^2-2l_j\cos s_j$. The critical case is $s_j=0$ and $s_{j+1}=\omega_j$. Then $e^2_j=(1-l_j)^2$ and $e_{j+1}^2=1+l_{j+1}^2-2l_{j+1}\cos \omega_j$. 
Since $0<\omega_j<\tfrac{\pi}2,$ we have

$$l_{j+1}\cos \omega_j=l_j\sqrt{1+2^{-2j}}\cdot \frac 1{\sqrt{1+\tan^2 \omega_j}}= l_j\sqrt{1+2^{-2j}}\cdot\frac 1{\sqrt{1+2^{-2j}}}=l_j.$$

So $e^2_j- e_{j+1}^2=l_j^2- l_{j+1}^2<0$.